# Solve non linear system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of two equations with two unknowns. In these equations I have, a part from constants:

- Unknown nr 1, $$D_{\perp}$$
- Unknown nr 2, $$\omega_C$$
- Known function of r: $$\mu(r)$$

The full system looks like:

equation1:
$$
D_{||}=
\frac 1 {2 \omega_0}(-\alpha-1)\sqrt{(-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||})^2+(\mu(r)D_{\perp})^2}+
\frac{\alpha}{2\omega_0}\sqrt{(-2\omega_0-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||})^2+(\mu(r)D_{\perp})^2}+
\frac{1}{2\omega_0}\sqrt{(2\omega_0-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||})^2+(\mu(r)D_{\perp})^2}
$$
and

equation2:
$$
1=
\mu(r)
\frac{\alpha}{2\omega_0}
\ln{\left[\frac{-2\omega_0-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||}+\sqrt{(-2\omega_0-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||})^2+(\mu(r)D_{\perp})^2}}{-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||}+\sqrt{(-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||})^2+(\mu(r)D_{\perp})^2}}\right]}+
\frac{\mu(r)}{2\omega_0}
\ln{\left[\frac{2\omega_0-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||}+\sqrt{(2\omega_0-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||})^2+(\mu(r)D_{\perp})^2}}
{-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||}+\sqrt{(-\omega_C+\mu(r)D_{||})^2+(\mu(r)D_{\perp})^2}}\right]}
$$

So the solution of the system of equations will be $$D_{\perp}(r),\;\omega_C(r)$$.

What I've tried to do is simply

```
    Solve[{equation1, equation2},{Dorthogonal, omegaC}]
```

but Mathematica keeps on running forever without any output. I have also tried:

```
    DorthFun[r_]:=Solve[{equation1, equation2},{Dorthogonal, omegaC}][[1,1]]
    omegaCFun[r_]:=Solve[{equation1, equation2},{Dorthogonal, omegaC}][[1,2]]
```

and it just keeps on running... It doesn't return any errors. Just...eternal running. Forrest Gump Syndrome...

I have also tried to solve the system putting $$\mu(r)=1$$ without any change.

I have given Mathematica about 20 minutes. Should I give it more time or does this mean that Mathematica cannot solve this? Or is there something I could do differently?

Thank you for your help!

My code looks like this:

```
    NSolve[{
    Dparallel==1/(2 omega0) Sqrt[(-omegaC + Dparallel)^2 + (Dorth)^2] (-alpha-1)+alpha/(2omega0)Sqrt[(-2omega0-omegaC+Dparallel)^2+(Dorth)^2]+1/(2omega0)Sqrt[(2omega0-omegaC+Dparallel)^2+(Dorth)^2],
    1 == alpha/(2omega0)Log[(-2omega0-omegaC+Dparallel+Sqrt[(-2omega0-omegaC+Dparallel)^2+(Dorth)^2])/(-omegaC+Dparallel+Sqrt[(-omegaC+Dparallel)^2+(Dorth)^2])]+1/(2omega0)Log[(2omega0-omegaC+Dparallel+Sqrt[(2omega0-omegaC+Dparallel)^2+(Dorth)^2])/(-omegaC+Dparallel+Sqrt[(-omegaC+Dparallel)^2+Sqrt[(-omegaC+Dparallel)^2+(Dorth)^2]])]
    }, {Dorth, omegaC}]
```

Comment: I think your problem are the "_". You can't use them as variables, those are used to define types of expressions. [Check it out](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecifyingTypesOfExpressionInPatterns.html).


Just change D_orthFun to DorthFun and D_orthogonal to Dorthogonal

Comment: I seem to have slipped when writing, my actual code has no underscores in the variable names. Thank you for the input though! I edited my question to include my code. I also tried NSolve as you can see but still with no end to the iterations.

Comment: What is the definition/value of `omega0`?

Comment: omega0=0.03. Why?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the correct way of showing an answer to a question I myself asked. But here is how I did anyway:

I used ContourPlot3D

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[{
(*29*)
Dparallel==1/(2 omega0) Sqrt[(-omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + (mu[r] Dorth)^2] (-alpha - 1) + 
  alpha/(2 omega0) Sqrt[(-2 omega0 - omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + (mu[r] Dorth)^2] +
  1/(2 omega0) Sqrt[(2 omega0 - omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + (mu[r] Dorth)^2],
(*30*)
1 == 
  alpha mu[r]/(2 omega0)*
  Log[(-2 omega0 - omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel + Sqrt[(-2 omega0 - omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + (mu[r] Dorth)^2])/
    (-omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel + Sqrt[(-omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + (mu[r] Dorth)^2])] +
  mu[r]/(2 omega0)*
  Log[(2 omega0 - omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel + Sqrt[(2 omega0 - omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + (mu[r] Dorth)^2])/
    (-omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel + Sqrt[(-omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + Sqrt[(-omegaC + mu[r] Dparallel)^2 + (mu[r] Dorth)^2]])]
}, {Dorth, -5, 5}, {omegaC, -5, 5}], {r, 0, 150}]
```

Where the solution to the system of equations would be where the surfaces intersect.

Unfortunately mine do not intersect... But now I know where to start!